# Attaching a Vagrant-hosted Gremlin-Server as a Data Source in PhpStorm

Tags: docker, vagrant, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, gremlin-server

I am running the Gremlin-Server from this [Tinkerpop Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tinkerpop/gremlin-server) within a Vagrant box. I am trying to link this server as a data source so that I can utilize the "Graph Database Console" plugin in PhpStorm. I am attempting to do this through the driver wizard workflow.

[image: PhpStorm Data sources and Drivers Window]

However, in the class dropdown it won't give me any configuration options other than `java.sql.Driver`. It does give me the option of connecting custom driver files, but I am not sure which file I would need to attach from the Gremlin-Server docker image.

What steps would it take to connect a Gremlin-Server as a data-source in PhpStorm?

Comment: You need JDBC driver (the common way how Java apps work with DBs). Look for one that works with your data source (if that exists of course). Other than that -- seems related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8505

Comment: In this case I am not sure that there is a JDBC related directly to the TinkerPop Gremlin-Server. It does have executables it runs in the server , but I wouldn't be sure how I might harness that on the PhpStorm side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the TinkerPop3 stack does not offer a JDBC Driver, as it is not neccessarily a database in-and-of itself. There is a [SQL port of Gremlin](https://github.com/twilmes/sql-gremlin) which is purportedly working on a JDBC driver for Gremlin-Server, but there is no option to currently reference a local hosted Gremlin-Server.

However in this instance there is a plugin for PhpStorm called [Graph Database Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8087-graph-database-support/) which allows you to then configure a Local Graph Database by pointing to your local environment and port. In my case it was a Vagrant IP address and a forwarded Docker port which meets that need.